# accelerate framework cepstrum peak find

Tags: objective-c, fft, accelerate-framework

I'm trying to find peak values of cepstrum analysis with accelerate framework. I get peak values always at the end of or at the beginning of frames. I'm analysing it real-time getting audio from microphone. What is wrong with this my code? My code is below :

```
OSStatus microphoneInputCallback (void                          *inRefCon, 
                              AudioUnitRenderActionFlags    *ioActionFlags, 
                              const AudioTimeStamp          *inTimeStamp, 
                              UInt32                        inBusNumber, 
                              UInt32                        inNumberFrames, 
                              AudioBufferList               *ioData){

// get reference of test app we need for test app attributes
TestApp *this = (TestApp *)inRefCon;
COMPLEX_SPLIT complexArray = this->fftA;
void *dataBuffer = this->dataBuffer;
float *outputBuffer = this->outputBuffer;
FFTSetup fftSetup = this->fftSetup;

uint32_t log2n = this->fftLog2n;
uint32_t n = this->fftN; // 4096
uint32_t nOver2 = this->fftNOver2;
uint32_t stride = 1;
int bufferCapacity = this->fftBufferCapacity; // 4096
SInt16 index = this->fftIndex;

OSStatus renderErr;

// observation objects
float *observerBufferRef = this->observerBuffer;
int observationCountRef = this->observationCount;

renderErr = AudioUnitRender(rioUnit, ioActionFlags, 
                            inTimeStamp, bus1, inNumberFrames, this->bufferList);
if (renderErr < 0) {
    return renderErr;
}

// Fill the buffer with our sampled data. If we fill our buffer, run the
// fft.
int read = bufferCapacity - index;
if (read > inNumberFrames) {
    memcpy((SInt16 *)dataBuffer + index, this->bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData, inNumberFrames*sizeof(SInt16));
    this->fftIndex += inNumberFrames;

} else {


    // If we enter this conditional, our buffer will be filled and we should PERFORM FFT.
    memcpy((SInt16 *)dataBuffer + index, this->bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData, read*sizeof(SInt16));

    // Reset the index.
    this->fftIndex = 0;

    /*************** FFT ***************/

    //multiply by window
    vDSP_vmul((SInt16 *)dataBuffer, 1, this->window, 1, this->outputBuffer, 1, n);

    // We want to deal with only floating point values here.
    vDSP_vflt16((SInt16 *) dataBuffer, stride, (float *) outputBuffer, stride, bufferCapacity );

    /** 
     Look at the real signal as an interleaved complex vector by casting it.
     Then call the transformation function vDSP_ctoz to get a split complex 
     vector, which for a real signal, divides into an even-odd configuration.
     */
    vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX*)outputBuffer, 2, &complexArray, 1, nOver2);

    // Carry out a Forward FFT transform.
    vDSP_fft_zrip(fftSetup, &complexArray, stride, log2n, FFT_FORWARD);

    vDSP_ztoc(&complexArray, 1, (COMPLEX *)outputBuffer, 2, nOver2);


    complexArray.imagp[0] = 0.0f;
    vDSP_zvmags(&complexArray, 1, complexArray.realp, 1, nOver2);
    bzero(complexArray.imagp, (nOver2) * sizeof(float));

    // scale
    float scale = 1.0f / (2.0f*(float)n);
    vDSP_vsmul(complexArray.realp, 1, &scale, complexArray.realp, 1, nOver2);

    // step 2 get log for cepstrum
    float *logmag = malloc(sizeof(float)*nOver2);
    for (int i=0; i < nOver2; i++)
        logmag[i] = logf(sqrtf(complexArray.realp[i]));


    // configure float array into acceptable input array format (interleaved)
    vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX*)logmag, 2, &complexArray, 1, nOver2);

    // create cepstrum
    vDSP_fft_zrip(fftSetup, &complexArray, stride, log2n-1, FFT_INVERSE);




    //convert interleaved to real
    float *displayData = malloc(sizeof(float)*n);
    vDSP_ztoc(&complexArray, 1, (COMPLEX*)displayData, 2, nOver2);



    float dominantFrequency = 0;
    int currentBin = 0;
    float dominantFrequencyAmp = 0;

    // find peak of cepstrum
    for (int i=0; i < nOver2; i++){
        //get current frequency magnitude

        if (displayData[i] > dominantFrequencyAmp) {
           // DLog("Bufferer filled %f", displayData[i]);
            dominantFrequencyAmp = displayData[i];
            currentBin = i;
        }
    }

    DLog("currentBin : %i amplitude: %f", currentBin,  dominantFrequencyAmp);

}
return noErr;
```

}

Comment: When you say at the beginning or end "of frames," what do you mean?  Do you mean windows?  There's only going to be one amplitude measurement per window...

Comment: yes i mean window, when buffer reaches to fftsize, code begins fft and ceptrum analysis

Comment: When you say "at the end or at the beginning" I don't understand, since you should only have one float value per bin per window...

Comment: i mean at the beginning index of displayData[i] or at the end index of displayData[i] value which stores cepstrum amplitude.So as you say beginning or end "bin" value of each window. I still couldn't find my mistake

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with the Accelerate Framework, but your code appears to be taking the proper steps to calculate the Cepstrum.

The Cepstrum of real acoustic signals tends to have a very large DC component, a large peak at and near zero quefrency [sic]. Just ignore the near-DC portion of the Cepstrum and look for peaks above 20 Hz frequency (above quefrency of Cepstrum_Width/20Hz).

If the input signal contains a series of very closely spaced overtones, the Cepstrum will also have a large peak at the high quefrency end.

For example, the plot below shows the Cepstrum of a Dirichlet Kernel of N=128 and Width=4096, the spectrum of which is a series of very closely spaced overtones.

[image: Dirichlet_Kernel_N128_Width4096]

You may want to use a static synthetic signal to test and debug your code. A good choice for a test signal is any sinusoid with a fundamental F and several overtones at exact integer multiples of F.

Your Cepstra should look something like the following examples.

First a synthetic signal.

The plot below shows the Cepstrum of a synthetic steady-state E2 note, synthesized using a typical near-DC component, a fundamental at 82.4 Hz, and 8 harmonics at integer multiples of 82.4 Hz. The synthetic sinusoid was programmed to generate 4096 samples.

Observe the prominent non-DC peak at 12.36.  The Cepstrum width is 1024 (the output of the second FFT), therefore the peak corresponds to 1024/12.36 = 82.8 Hz which is very close to 82.4 Hz the true fundamental frequency.

[image: Cepstrum of synthetic E2 note]

Now a real acoustical signal.

The plot below shows the Cepstrum of a real acoustic guitar's E2 note. The signal was not windowed prior to the first FFT. Observe the prominent non-DC peak at 542.9.  The Cepstrum width is 32768 (the output of the second FFT), therefore the peak corresponds to 32768/542.9 = 60.4 Hz which is fairly far from 82.4 Hz the true fundamental frequency.

[image: Cepstrum of acoustic guitar E2 note, not windowed]

The plot below shows the Cepstrum of the same real acoustic guitar's E2 note, but this time the signal was Hann windowed prior to the first FFT. Observe the prominent non-DC peak at 268.46.  The Cepstrum width is 32768 (the output of the second FFT), therefore the peak corresponds to 32768/268.46 = 122.1 Hz which is even farther from 82.4 Hz the true fundamental frequency.

[image: Cepstrum of acoustic guitar E2 note, Hann windowed]

The acoustic guitar's E2 note used for this analysis was sampled at 44.1 KHz with a high quality microphone under studio conditions, it contains essentially zero background noise, no other instruments or voices, and no post processing.

References:

Real audio signal data, synthetic signal generation, plots, FFT, and Cepstral analysis were done here: [Musical instrument cepstrum](https://sooeet.com/music/musical-instrument-cepstrum.php)

Comment: Babson thanks for your very detail answer it helped me a lot. In fir st plot you have a peak at bin 1024. What is this time corresponding value? For example your sample rate 44100. Each bin takes 1/44100. So 1024 * (1/44100) gives time value of cepstrum bin? Is is true?

Comment: The time at which signal events occur cannot be determined from either Spectrum or Cepstrum data. If you need to resolve the time of a signal event as it relates to frequency, you must calculate a Spectrogram of the signal, and you must choose an appropriate window-size for the short-time FFT used to calculate the Spectrogram. A carefully constructed and properly tuned Spectrogram will allow you to resolve the temporal events of your interest, as they relate to frequency.